# View frame changes when hiding the status bar iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am trying to solve this issue for a while,

I have a view controller embedded in a navigation controller and I want to toggle the status bar hide/show.

The problem is when I set the status bar to be hidden my all view including the navigation bar jumps up.

How can I avoid this behavior?
I just want to hide the status bar without any other effects, and with the navigation bar staying extended from 0 to 64 px height.

I created a [simple project](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=A058C132E2551E56!108&authkey=!AAuuLhUxDoyMOes&ithint=file,.zip) that demonstrate the problem.

Few notes about possible solution:
- I cant use auto layout
- the navigation bar cant be translucent
- "View controller-based status bar appearance" must be is set to NO

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I would recommend that you modify your desires. The behavior you're describing is built deeply into UINavigationController, so, basically, you can't do what you're describing without writing your own UINavigationController subclass - though, to be even more honest, it is far from clear to me what you'd have to override to interfere with this behavior, so it might be necessary to write a substitute interface. For example, you could have a presented view controller containing a navigation bar and your interface, and now you are in complete control of the height and position of everything... It sounds to me like this is a road that isn't worth going down.

Comment: i tried to simplify the problem as much as I can, my real UI structure is a scroll view with 3 views, and user can slide between them left and right like Snapchat, and like snapchat I want to hide the status bar for the middle view and show it when user slides left/right to the other views.

Comment: "modify your desires" = trivial. The problem is modifying the desires of the client.

Answer (score 0):

First change the all your view and button springs and struts to

[image]

and then change your code to

```
- (IBAction)toggleStatusBar:(UIButton *)sender {
    _hidden = !_hidden;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:_hidden withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        CGRect frame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame ;

        _hidden?(frame.size.height +=20):(frame.size.height -=0);
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame = frame;

        CGRect frame2 = self.view.frame ;

        _hidden?(frame2.origin.y +=20):(frame2.origin.y -=0);
        _hidden?(frame2.size.height -=20):(frame.size.height -=0);

        self.view.frame = frame2;

    }];

}
```

you have to set animation else it will cause problem and show black area when hiding status bar.

Comment: the problem here is that the navigation bar moving when animating